# DOMPDF - show custom text on image using css

Tags: php, css, pdf, pdf-generation, dompdf

I am trying to show custom text on the image using dompdf

```
<div class="image" style="font-size:25px">
  <img alt="" src="image-url.jpg" />
  <div class="name" style="margin-top: -575px; margin-right: 0; margin-bottom: 0; margin-left: 235px; position: absolute;">
    <font face="High Tower Text"><em><?php print $some-value; ?></em></font>
 </div>
 <div class="current-date" style="margin-top :-510px; margin-right: 0; margin-bottom: 0; margin-left: 235px; position: absolute;">
    <font face="High Tower Text"><em><?php print $some-value; ?></em></font>
  </div>
</div>
```

but when i try to open it in pdf, first it print image and after that it print the dynamic text, which i am providing.

Answer (score 2):

The upcoming release (0.6.0) will have absolute and fixed positioning support. You can try out the updates in the  [0.6.0 beta release](http://code.google.com/p/dompdf/downloads/list) which includes this functionality. I [created a sample document](http://eclecticgeek.com/dompdf/index.php?input_file=so3127042.htm&dompdf_ver=0.6.0_beta1) using your HTML so you can see the new functionality in action.

Answer (score 1):

DOMPDF [does not support](http://www.digitaljunkies.ca/dompdf/css21.php) `position: absolute`.

There was an [issue](http://code.google.com/p/dompdf/issues/detail?id=5&q=position%20absolute) posted, but looks like it hasn't been added yet.

A workaround might be to render the image with your text in [GD](http://php.net/manual/en/book.image.php)
.

Comment: Thanks alex for your quick response.